# Is it possible to get output of a NRQL query in new relic using a jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, newrelic, nrql

I'm looking to automate the process of collecting data from New Relic Insights and sharing it over a  mail accepting start and end time for a particular nrql query. There is a New Relic Insights plugin for jenkins that is available but not sure if such a task is possible using that? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a REST API for Insights that will let you senda NRQL query and retrieve the results in JSON format. You might take a look at that.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/insights-api/get-data/query-insights-event-data-api

Comment: I did have a look at the API yesterday but I could not quite understand how I need to proceed (I'm pretty new to this). I'll give you an example and may be you could help me understand on how to proceed with this.
SELECT count, sum, average, min, max FROM Transaction WHERE appName= 'XYZ' FACET SomeCol SINCE '2017-06-07 03:58:00 CDT' UNTIL '2017-06-07 04:43:00 CDT' limit 1000
I went to to my Insights > Manage data > API keys > Query keys (+) and added my query. How do I call this particular query from jenkins job (I'm new to jenkins so any links or brief explanation would be really helpful)